# expect utility is not working when executing from jenkins

Tags: linux, jenkins, hudson, solaris, expect

we have a unix script which uses expect utility for interactive execution. This script works well when we run from unix server.

If we run this script from Jenkins, it is not working.

Below is the script

```
var="xxxxx"
expect -c "
    spawn sudo cp /abcd/sjws/config/obj.conf /abcd/sjws/config/obj.conf_jenkins
    expect {
    "Password:" { send $var\r;interact }
    }
    exit
    "
```

Below is the output when we run from jenkins

```
spawn sudo cp /abcd/sjws/config/obj.conf /abcd/sjws/config/obj.conf_jenkins 
Password: 
Password:
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure 
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: I wonder if the problem is the way the shell is expanding the $var variable into the expect script: try changing `send $var\r` to `send \"$var\r\"`

Answer (score 14):

Since Jenkins doesn't run it from an actual terminal, `interact` doesn't work, since there can't actually be any user interaction there.

You can replace `interact` with

```
expect eof
wait
```

Comment: Thank you! Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: This worked when jenkins is running in CentOS but not when running on Ubuntu. The build just hangs when it's on Ubuntu. Do you have any insight into this? Please let me know ..Thanks

Comment: Perhaps the spawned process doesn't exit in Ubuntu for some reason? Maybe it's still waiting for input, due to previous mishandled expectations?

Comment: Thank you! Saved my week! :)

Comment: Got the same problem while using sshpass. This fixed it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please use var='xxxxx' instead of var="xxxxx". Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Jenkins doesn't support the interactive command model.

Try to use **sshpass** tool to pass the password in a non-interactive way.

[install sshpass](http://www.nextstep4it.com/sshpass-command-non-interactive-ssh/)

```
$ sshpass -p "password" {your command}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is very similar to: [Jenkins not waiting on call to a bash script with expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478611/jenkins-not-waiting-on-call-to-a-bash-script-with-expect/40087426#40087426); for those encountering the similar problem, **especially** when using "**su**" utility to change the user, please be aware that Jenkins closes the SSH connection as soon as the user is changed. You can not continue giving commands with the new user. Design your script in such a way that you are sending the command directly, such as:

```
spawn su - username -c "yoursinglewordcommand"
```

and then the rest of the expect script as usual (I was also successful with the interact command).

Answer (score 0):

You may use [ssh steps plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-steps-plugin). This plugin will provide steps like sshScript which executes given script(file) on remote node and responds with output, sshCommand that executes given command on remote node and responds with output and also sshPut, sshGet, sshRemove.

Add to your Jenkinsfile :

```
node {
   def remote = [:]
   remote.name = 'test'
   remote.host = 'test.domain.com'
   remote.user = 'root'
   remote.password = 'password'
   remote.allowAnyHosts = true
   stage('Remote SSH') {
      sshCommand remote: remote, command: "cp /abcd/sjws/config/obj.conf /abcd/sjws/config/obj.conf_jenkins"
  }
}
```