# Jenkins integration with expect scripts

Tags: linux, jenkins, tcl, expect

We have an automation suite, written in tcl and perl, which works on linux. We want to integrate this suite with Jenkins. Scripts of this suite are using `expect` to expect a particular prompt after evry command execution. For eg:

```
switch -- $m2gelgd_number {
    m2gelgd {
            set elgms [concat $ELGMS\_$MS_CLASS\_$MS_NUMBER]
            send -- "cd $GEMU_CONFIG_PATH\r"
            expect "]#"

      send -- "scp $elgmsroot@$GEMU_MSBTS_IP:$GEMU/system/macros/elgms_macros.mac\r"
             expect "# "

exec sh /root/GEMUAUTOMATION/FUNCTION/gemu_m2_start.sh $GEMU_MSBTS_IP $GEMU_M2GELGD  &
             expect "# "
            }
```

With Jenkins, we are facing the error of

> "Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure"

whereas on manual execution, the code works fine.
Can anyone let us know what could be the issue?

Comment: I see scp in there. Are you relying on ssh keys? Does jenkins run as the right user to pick up the right key?

Comment: Was there any output before that point which might indicate _why_ there is a failure?

Comment: Hi Glenn, Yes we have used the concept of ssh keys. But, I dont think the issue lies with scp here because scp in another function is working fine with Jenkins. Is there any way to check how Jenkins operates where ssh keys are used?

Comment: Hi Donal , No there was no output before this point. The xterm windows , that are opened by the script could be seen on the linux machine where the script was started, but other than that no output was observed.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my answer to: [expect utility is not working when executing from jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914342/expect-utility-is-not-working-when-executing-from-jenkins/40087585#40087585), changing the expect call to a single line command should solve the problem.