# Jenkins not waiting on call to a bash script with expect

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, expect

I have a Jenkins job and on the "Execute shell" window I am calling a small application that copies files to some host.

The problem is: If I run the script (shown bellow as ./relmanager ...) manually via SSH on a console to the host where Jenkins is running, everything works fine, like:

```
[{USER}@{JENKINS_SERVER} release_manager]$ ./relmanager {USER} {PASSWD} u 2014_12_040 i 10.83.206.44
> Verifying configuration files...
spawn scp -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -C -r 2014_12_040 root@10.83.206.44:/srv/releases/
Password:
fpga-rw.tgz                100% 7587     7.4KB/s   00:00
resetclear.tgz             100%  287     0.3KB/s   00:00
....
```

But if I ask Jenkins to run it for me, it seems that it doesn't wait and quits immediately, and I see this on the console output of the job: (note that I used set -/+ x to see the commands)

```
+ ./relmanager {USER} {PASSWD} u 2014_12_040 i 10.83.206.44
> Verifying configuration files...
spawn scp -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -C -r 2014_12_040 root@10.83.206.44:/srv/releases/
Password: + set +x
```

And nothing else is done, just quits without waiting the ~1-2mins the copy takes...

Here is what I have: The "Execute shell" looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
#(variables assigned here)
cd $RELEASE_MANAGER
./relmanager $SVN_USER $SVN_PASSWD u $PS_REL i $HOST_IP_ADDR
...
```

I know that the application relmanager (written in bash) internally calls an expect script. Inside the application 'relmanager':

```
relmanager_etc/copy_expect $IP $REL_NAME
```

And contents of 'copy_expect' script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 10
set IP [lindex $argv 0]
set REL_NAME [lindex $argv 1]
spawn scp -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -C -r $REL_NAME root@$IP:/srv/releases/
expect "Password:"
send "root\r";
interact
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Even if I add directly the expect script to Jenkins, it also does not wait for the command to complete. Changing timeout inside the expect script does not change the behavior as well:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
#(variables defined here)
./copy_expect $IP $REL_NAME
...
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Adding exp_internal to the expect script to show log (Tip from Etan Reisner):

Running on jenkins:

```
spawn scp -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -C -r 2014_12_040 root@10.83.206.44:/srv/releases/
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {13601}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "*assword:"? no
Password: 
expect: does "Password: " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "*assword:"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Password:"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Password:"
send: sending "root\r" to { exp6 }
spawn id exp6 sent <\r\n>

interact: received eof from spawn_id exp0
write() failed to write anything - will sleep(1) and retry...
write() failed to write anything - will sleep(1) and retry...
```

And the same thing but running via terminal:

```
[{USER}@{JENKINS_SERVER} release_manager]$ ./copy_expect 10.83.206.44 2014_12_040
spawn scp -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -C -r 2014_12_040 root@10.83.206.44:/srv/releases/
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {27464}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "*assword:"? no
Password:
expect: does "Password: " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "*assword:"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Password:"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Password:"
send: sending "root\r" to { exp6 }
tty_raw_noecho: was raw = 0  echo = 1
spawn id exp6 sent <\r\n>

spawn id exp6 sent <\rfpga-rw.tgz                                                                                                                  0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA\rfpga-rw.tgz                                                                                                                100% 7587     7.4KB/s   00:00    \r\n>
fpga-rw.tgz                                                                                                                100% 7587     7.4KB/s   00:00
spawn id exp6 sent <\rresetclear.tgz                                                                                                               0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA\rresetclear.tgz                                                                                                             100%  287     0.3KB/s   00:00    \r\n>
resetclear.tgz                                                                                                             100%  287     0.3KB/s   00:00
...
```

Comment: Does it wait ten seconds and then give up? Does changing the value of `timeout` change how long it waits before giving up?

Comment: Might be better to set up a key so you don't use password login.

Comment: @EtanReisner, using Jenkins it never waits 10 seconds, its almost immediately, although i see that on the destination host, the folder is created and 3 files are created, 1st and 2nd have few KB, the 3rd one is never finished (its trimmed) as it is bigger than 20MB

Comment: @stark, I know it would be. The problem is that the application is very complex and it is used by several users. It would be great to make jenkins wait like it would happen on a normal terminal...

Comment: Have you tried changing the timeout? I'd still bet on that working. And using a key wouldn't change the timeout/etc. behaviour it would just mean you don't need to use expect to script the `scp`.

Comment: @EtanReisner, Ive tried with timeout of 100 and nothing solved. Seems that copying the 3 files or not even creating the folder is completely random and maybe dependent on the load of Jenkins.

Comment: Is 100 enough to send the files when jenkins is busy? Does your `relmanager` script log the output and return code from `copy_expect`? Can you add `exp_internal 1` to the top of the expect script to see expect debugging information about data received, etc.?

Comment: @EtanReisner. Yes its enough, but even with 100 the jenkins job finishes under 3 seconds. No, it does not log the output, but I will use only the copy_expect script straight from jenkins shell as above in UPDATE 1 while debugging the problem. The debugging info from expect is on UPDATE 2

Comment: Try getting rid of `interact`? There isn't a user in the script context and I bet that is screwing things up.

Comment: @EtanReisner, well, I got rid of `interact` and used `wait` instead, it worked, but I had to divide the relmanager application into single steps.
Although I still have one problem, when using `wait` it seems to work, but i have no command output, so I have no idea what is being done. Is there any way of forwarding the stdout of my scp/ssh command to jenkins when using this expect with `wait`?

Comment: I would think that would be the default but I don't know. This is a bit beyond my experience level with expect unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins closes the SSH connection as soon as the user is changed or your interaction with the script is completed. Design your script in such a way that you are waiting for the script to be completed in Jenkins. By doing this, you will ensure that your transfer is not interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

basically : if your script uses expect script with

spawn -noecho ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no $user@$ip
send ...

what you "send" is actually sent to the bash script you are running and NOT to the ssh spawned because Jenkins is closing the spawned ssh .

The solution I found is : 
 1- let the jenkins user to ssh w/o passwd to his own user at local host

2- in your bash script do:   ssh your-user@jenkins-host expect ....